# iOS UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive disables text field interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

On iOS7 app, I have a bunch of UITextFields on an UIScrollView that scrolls vertically.
I set the `scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;`

Now, I am able to dismiss the keyboard by dragging the scroll view. The first time I dismiss a keyboard this way, something happens: 
I can no longer edit any of the UITextFields. As if their `userInteractionEnabled` was set to `NO`. Cursor does not appear inside a text field. Keyboard does not appear.

I do not know why my text fields become unresponsive after the first time I dismiss a keyboard interactively. Has anyone encountered this problem?

EDIT:

If I call `[self.view endEditing:YES];` I get a very strange behaviour (screenshot attached). A large upper portion of the screen becomes gray. When I rotate the device, the gray rectangle moves to the bottom and the text fields become responsive again.

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem I was experiencing had nothing to do with `scrollView.keyboardDismissMode`. It had a lot to do with messing with scroll view's content offsets and insets.

I found that my view controller had been set as the delegate for the vertical scroll view. 
And it had implemented one of the delegate methods:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    }
}
```

This was a poor hack attempt to do what can otherwise easily be done by:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

So I deleted `scrollViewDidScroll` method, un-set the delegate for the scroll view and put the `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` on top of my view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Now, it works great.